# Black screen on resume from suspend to RAM

Tags: linux, suspend

I have Xubuntu(12.04) and Fedora17KDE spin installed on my netbook. While Xubuntu wakes up neatly, Fedora gets stuck at the black screen while resuming. After going through the `pm-suspend.log` file I realized that `vbetools` was not installed. I installed the `vbetools` package. Still resume throws up a black screen. Now the log file has something different to say:

```
Thu Aug 16 16:07:46 IST 2012: performing suspend
Thu Aug 16 16:07:51 IST 2012: Awake.
Thu Aug 16 16:07:51 IST 2012: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /usr/lib64/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
Function not supported
```

Also `vbetools` was having trouble with SELinux. I went ahead and disabled SELinux. I don't think that has anything to do with this. I have come across many similar posts but am not able to find a solution.

Here is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Cedarview Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Slightly off-topic:  Also the brightness keys won't work. I manage to change the brightness using the setpci method.

Comment: Welcome to SE U&L.  I just added [some formatting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), hope you don't mind.

Comment: Upgraded the kernel and everything works fine now. 
The current kernel version reads 3.5.3-1.